# Saving and loading history automatically

Tags: r, history, profile

I'm using the R software for statistical analysis and am sad that it doesn't preserve and restore my prompt command history. Indeed, pressing the up arrow on a newly started interactive R session will reveal a blank history, every time. It would be great if it could do this in manner, say, similar to `ipython`. I tried putting this in my `.Rprofile` file to no avail. No file containing my command history is ever created.

```
.First <- function(){
        if (!any(commandArgs()=='--no-readline') && interactive()){
                require(utils)
                try(loadhistory(Sys.getenv("R_HISTFILE")))
        }
}

.Last <- function() {
        if (!any(commandArgs()=='--no-readline') && interactive()){
                require(utils)
                try(savehistory(Sys.getenv("R_HISTFILE")))
        }
}
```

Of course this line is present in my `.bash_profile`

```
export R_HISTFILE="$HOME/share/r_libs/.history"
```

All this is happening via SSH on a remote server running Linux. Any help greatly appreciated !

Comment: Not really an answer, but most people I think recommend saving the commands you want to use again in a script.  Then you don't have to wade through your entire history to find the few commands you want.

Comment: Yeah of course I'll write my final pipeline in a script; but imagine using something like the bash shell without history preservation across sessions, wouldn't you get frustrated too ?

Comment: Not really, no.  I type commands I want to keep in my script, and one-offs in the console.  Actually, I get frustrated when I forget to put something I want later in my script and have to wade through my history to find it.

Comment: You don't mention what UI you're using - maybe try RStudio or similar?

Comment: @hadley I'm just launching the R prompt from the bash shell after connecting to a node on the cluster with SSH.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies a lot about what kind of solutions are possible and why you care about the history.  Does hadley's solution work for you?

Answer (score 14):

In my `~/.profile` I have:

```
export R_HISTFILE=~/.Rhistory
```

In my `~/.Rprofile` I have:

```
if (interactive()) {
  .Last <- function() try(savehistory("~/.Rhistory"))
}
```

and that works for me (although it doesn't work very well if you have multiple R sessions open)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It will load what ever is in `~/.Rhistory` but will not save at the end of each session unless I answer yes to the save workspace image question.

Comment: @xApple I also have `alias R='R --no-save --no-restore-data --quiet'` in my profile which eliminates the questions on close.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to setting `.Last` is registering a finalizer for `.GlobalEnv`, which will be run even if the R session is exited with EOF (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> elsewhere):

```
if (interactive()) {
  invisible(
    reg.finalizer(
      .GlobalEnv,
      eval(bquote(function(e) try(savehistory(file.path(.(getwd()), ".Rhistory"))))),
      onexit = TRUE))
}
```

There are some extra bells and whistles here:

- `invisible()` makes sure the return value of `reg.finalizer()` isn't printed when R starts up
- Contrary to Hadley's answer, the `.Rhistory` file is saved in the current directory. `eval(bquote(... .(getwd()) ...))` evaluates `getwd()` during startup, so that the directory that is current during startup is used at exit
- Setting `onexit = TRUE` makes sure that the code is actually run

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Rgui : `savehistory()`, `loadhistory()` and `history()` could do the job. Otherwise I guess it depends on the IDE..

Comment: I'm not interested in saving my session at the moment. I just wanted my history to be preserved. I'm not using any IDE yet.

Comment: First answer was off topic, i'm so tired

Comment: Yes, I have identified the `savehistory()` and `loadhistory()` commands. I'm asking how to have this happen automatically at each new session creation.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider emacs and ESS, which work fine over SSH and allow for the more usual (and generally considered more powerful) method of keeping useful commands in a separate file.

Comment: could you comment more on cons and pros of using ESS and give a tutorial?

Comment: That would be a great answer, but unfortunately more than I am up to providing.  My best answer is to find a friendly colleague who uses it and go from there.  It's different enough from most "modern" programs that having a helping hand in person is especially helpful.